# Add a border to a UIView not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to add a border to a UIView inside a custom cell. I am trying:

```
partial class EventCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public EventCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

    }

    public void SetUpCell(Event eventObj)
    {
        title.Text = eventObj.title;
        cellFooter.Layer.BorderColor = new MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor (224f, 224f, 224f);
        cellFooter.Layer.BorderWidth = 5.0f;
        cellFooter.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cellFooter.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGB(224,224,224).CGColor;` instead of creating a new CGcolor fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Add the 'clipsToBounds' property as below

```
cellFooter.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
cellFooter.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
cellFooter.clipsToBounds= YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it just in function drawRect, then fill this code

```
cellFooter.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
cellFooter.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use view's layer to set border property. e.g:

## import

...

```
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
view.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
```

You also need to link with QuartzCore.framework to access this functionality.

Comment: the views name is `cellFooter` so I am doing exactly this.